# Add child list inside parent list on matching condition

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I am having two lists

```
class A{ int id; string name; string type; List<B> listB;}
class B{int id; int refid; string value;}    

ListofA[{id=1,name="ABC",type="A",listB=null},id=1,name="ABC",type="A",listB=null}]
ListofB[{id=4,refid=1,value="ABC"},{id=5,refid=1,value="DEF"},{id=6,refid=2,value="XYZ"},]
```

I want to add matching objects of B to listB of class A. condition should be A.id == B.id. I tried below approach but I am getting blank list.

```
ListofA = ListofA.Select(a => new A { id = a.id, name =a.name,type = a.type,
                                      listB = listOfB.Where(b => b.refid == a.id).ToList()}).ToList();
```

Is there anything missed from me.
Can any one please help me in this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: your code has syntax bugs. What should ListofA represent? You have more "}" than "{"

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten your code removing the whole syntax errors there. So you will get the desired output (no blank list):

```
class A {public int id; public string name; public string type;public  List<B> listB; }
class B { public int id;public  int refid; public string value; }
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   List<A> ListofA = new List<A>{
       new A() { id = 1,name = "ABC",type = "A",listB = null},
       new A() { id = 2,name = "XYZ",type = "A",listB = null}
   };

    List<B> listOfB = new List<B>{
        new B() { id =4,refid=1,value="ABC"},
        new B() { id=5,refid=1,value="DEF"},
        new B() { id=6,refid=2,value="XYZ"}}         ;

    var ListofA2 = ListofA.Select(a => new A
        {
            id = a.id,
            name = a.name,
            type = a.type,
            listB = listOfB.Where(b => b.refid == a.id).ToList()
        }
    ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for code refactoring. But, I am still getting blank list

Comment: How you get blank list? There is no possible.

Answer (score -1):

I made a silly mistake, because of that I was getting blank list. I made the changes and its working good now. Thanks for your help

Comment: please post this as comment, or an edit to your post where you describe your mistake and the changes you made. This answer has no value for anyone who might visit this post in the future. Thanx and a happy new year ;)

Comment: *"I made the changes and its working good now"* What changes?